# Solr Search with 2 text fields

Tags: search

I have a drupal 7 installation with apache solr search: But I need to use a custom search like this:

2 TextBox fields with:
What -> Any word of the apache index.
AND
Where -> A term reference in the content type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking for several forums and apache solr help, I made it like this...

Notes:

1 $form_state['values']['keys'] - The search text

2 $form_state['values']['localidade'] - The taxonomy term search value

function MYMODULE_search_block_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {

```
// Check if localidade is empty
    if (empty($form_state['values']['localidade'])) {
    // localidade empty
        drupal_goto('pesquisa/' . $form_state['values']['keys']);
    } else {
    // with localidade
    // check what is the tid of my term localidade
        $t1 = $form_state['values']['localidade'];
        $t2 = taxonomy_get_term_by_name($t1, "localidade");
        $t3 = array_shift($t2);
    // term no found
        if (empty($t3->tid)) {
            drupal_set_message('Não reconheçemos a localidade ' . $form_state['values']['localidade'] . ', por favor coloque uma localidade sugerida.');
            drupal_goto('pesquisa/');
        } else {
    // build search parameter with the term tid
            $t11 = 'pesquisa/' . $form_state['values']['keys'];
            $options['query']['search_param'] = 'f[0]=bundle:empresa&f[1]=im_field_localidade:' . $t3->tid;
            drupal_goto($t11, $options);
        }

 }
```

}